# Fusing pressure/depth sensor/IMU for Nav2

Tags: ros2, imu, ros-humble, sensor-fusion, nav2

Can I fuse a depth sensor or a pressure sensor's readings with imu to publish /odom (odometry) in Nav2 stack? I don't have wheel encoders in my robot, and I don't know what to use. Any resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for a package that will do that, you can use `robot_localization`, but you'll run into some trouble. Your IMU, at most, will give you linear acceleration, rotational velocity, and absolute orientation. A pressure sensor, once converted to a depth measurement, will provide Z position. Without a reference for either X and Y position or at least X and Y velocity, your state estimate is going to explode.

We're also aiming to deprecate `robot_localization` in favor of `fuse`, but we need to implement some 3D sensor models first.

https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html
https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/fuse_doc/html/index.html